# how to prevent loadbalancer from going offline?

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, load-balancing

i plan to setup a load balancer for a webproject but there is a major issue in my head:

a typical loadbalancer would be: (provided by nginx upstream) Server #1 accepts all requests and forwards them to server #2 - server#n but what happens when server #1 is under such heavy load that he cannot handle the requests properly and maybe goes down or slows down really mad?

how can you prevent this? i could think of maybe dns based loadbalancing or something.

I do not need session persistence or something else. this is just for an api where each request authenticates itself.

have you any ideas?

thanks for your feedback

Comment: [What if](https://what-if.xkcd.com) questions are not [the best ones to ask](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) on ServerFault. - As a general rule you need a lot of traffic for a loadbalancer to reach it's limit. When you do, using DNS is one way to distribute users over multiple loadbalancers and application stacks. Typically that is round robin DNS  but also the time that you may be considering bringing your content closer to your end-users with distributed datacenter locations and may consider using Geo DNS and/or anycast.

Comment: The common approach is to have a redundant pair of load-balancers (with session replication if that is important). You do performance testing to validate/improve you configuration and monitor.

Answer (score 0):

"what happens when server #1 is under such heavy load that he cannot handle the requests properly"

Usually clients get "connection timed out" error message.

Don't worry about the load balancer : with modern hardware, they can handle thousands of requests, especially if you use cache for static content.

Most of the time, the bottlenecks are :

- network bandwidth
- server #2 - server#n who tipically have to compute dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

> how can you prevent this?

You can't. You can only plan for certain supported load scenarios. Your nginx LB may handle more connection attempts than your API servers that do the heavy parts. And there is always the possibility that bad guys test you out or DDoS you.

Your LB server also needs maintenance and restarts so you might eventually setup something that competes with products that already solved the security and scalability problem like the [Amazon API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/?nc1=h_ls) or [DigitalOceans Loadbalancers](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/load-balancer/).